# 1 line text view next to two line text view

Tags: android

I was wondering if this can be implemented in android.

[image]

So there are basically two text views one is the name / other is the "open" .
The name can extend more than one line and the "open" should be placed adjacently .
One way is to dynamically break the name text view into two and place "open" next to it. But I don't find it good solution . any direct way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought .
It can be done via setting text using `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));`

Answer (score 0):

You may set the following to your TextView:

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_image"
```

Comment: aligning to the right is not major thing . the problem is aligning just exactly right to where the text end... the first text view would become rectangle .. and close will get pushed leaving bottom to 'Pizzeria' area blank..

Answer (score 0):

You could create `ListView` and use 
[setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://goo.gl/UjBWh) in the layout for your `Adapter`. Create a `Boolean` to show when a pizza joint is open and when to show the `Drawable`.

Something like this:

```
if (isOpen){
yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0, drawable);
}
```

Of course, this would require you to make an "**open**" image, but the way I see it, this would be the easiest way.

Comment: I have multiple languages to do... "open" image solution doesn't work for me